# XPath for multiple rows in the same table

Tags: html, web-scraping, xpath

I'm trying to write XPath for certain rows for a scraper. Here's the given XPath for only the first row in the table: /html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[8]/div/table/tbody/tr[1]

I need to extract only certain values that relate to certain values in the first column. For example, the first column has dates and second column has data corresponding to those dates. I need to write XPath for only certain rows that contain dates '2015-03-14', '2014-02-15' and so on. Is there a way to add multiple values like this?

So far I've tried the contains operator but it only works for one value [contains(.,'2015-03-14')]. I want to add multiple dates.

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
tr[td[1][contains(.,'2015-03-14') or contains(.,'2014-02-15')]]/td[2]
```

If besides whitespace there is nothing more in that first column you could also just use the `=` operator using the normalized-space value, like this:

```
tr[td[1][normalize-space()[.='2015-03-14' or .='2014-02-15']]]/td[2]
```

It finds those second td's who has a first td with one of your dates.

I skipped the path to the tr's for readability, but this: `/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[8]/div/table/tbody/`, has to be added off course